# Shellcode mov instruction error

Tags: assembly, shellcode

I have been working on shellcodes recently. I wrote a shellcode to spawn a shell using execve syscall.

Here is the assembly code:

```
global _start

section .text

_start:

        jmp Shellcode

Execve:

        xor rax, rax

        ; Get the address of the string
        pop rdi

        ; Convert the A -> 0x0 to null terminate the string
        mov [rdi +7], byte ah

        ; Copy the address of the string in RDI to BBBBBBBB
        mov [rdi +8], rdi

        ; Copy the NULL 0x0000000000000000 -> CCCCCCCC
        mov [rdi +16], rax

        ; Setup the addresses
        lea rsi, [rdi +8]
        lea rdx, [rdi +16]

        add rax, 59
        syscall


Shellcode:

        call Execve

        shell_string : db "/bin/shABBBBBBBBCCCCCCCC"
```

I compile this code with this.

- > nasm -f elf64 execve-jmp-call-pop.nasm -o execve-jmp-call-pop.o
- > ld execve-jmp-call-pop.o -o execve-jmp-call-pop

When I run this program it gives me segmentation fault. I loaded this program in gdb and it gives segmentation fault on * mov [rdi +7], byte ah* instruction. I try to look at rax and ah register value but gdb says it cant be accessed.I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit OS in Virtual box. I am new at this. I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: You are not allowed to write to the text segment. It's a security feature to make exploits harder to write.  :-)

Comment: Your `shell_string` is in the `.text` section, which is likely to be read-only.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. When I use this in stack It works fine.